# How to create instances of complex class in a better practice?

Tags: java, c#, typescript, oop

As a newbie, I'm developing a game but puzzling about **a better way to create complex objects**. This issue can be about **OOP, design pattern and SOLID-principle**.For these questions, there're few programming language limits.

The situation is clear:

1. One warship consists of one body and several turrets.
2. One turret consists of one shield and several barrels.

#### Background

I'm developing a browser-based 2D game using Pixi.js with TypeScript. The following classes are inherited from Sprite or Container, the native classes of Pixi.js, but I omitted these extend clauses in the code below for the sake of clearance and to the point.

#### Code

I can simply think up the code for Barrel, Shield and Body below: (in TypeScript, but there're few differences with Java and C#, isn't it?)

```
class Barrel {
  constructor(texture, x, y, rotation){
    /*...*/
  }
}
class Shield {
  constructor(texture, x, y, rotation){
    /*...*/
  }
}
class Body {
  constructor(texture, x, y, rotation){
    /*...*/
  }
}
```

**Here comes the question**, what about a turret and a warship?

Roughly, 1 turret = 1 shield + N barrel(s), and 1 warship = 1 body + N turret(s).

Without further detailed thinking, code below can be easily got:

```
class Turret {
  private shield: Shield
  private barrels: Barrel[]
  constructor(x, y, rotation, shieldCfg, barrelCfgList) {
    /*...*/
    this.shield = new Shield(shieldCfg.texture, shieldCfg.x, shieldCfg.y, shieldCfg.rotation)
    for(let cfg of barrelCfgList){
      const barrel = new Barrel(cfg.texture, cfg.x, cfg.y, cfg.rotation)
      this.barrels.push(barrel)
    }
  }
}

class Warship {
  private body: Body
  private turrets: Turret[]
  constructor(x, y, rotation, bodyCfg, turretCfgList) {
    /*...*/
    this.body = new Body(bodyCfg.texture, bodyCfg.x, bodyCfg.y, bodyCfg.rotation)
    for(let cfg of turretCfgList){
      const turret = new Turret(cfg.x, cfg.y, cfg.rotation, cfg.shieldCfg, cfg.barrelCfgList)
      this.turrets.push(turret)
    }
  }
}
```

And it's not hard to imagine how complicated the *turretCfgList* can be.

```
const turretCfgList = [
  {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    rotation: 3.14,
    shieldCfg: {
      texture: 'gun-shield'
      x: 4,
      y: 5,
      rotation: 6.28
    },
    barrelCfgList: [
      {
        texture: 'gun-barrel'
        x: 7,
        y: 8,
        rotation: 9.42
      },
      /*...*/
    ]
  },
  /*...*/
]
```

#### My questions are:

1. How to solve the complex parameter of nested objects above?
2. What's the improvements between the raw code above, and the better solutions in Factory Method Pattern, Builder Pattern and etc?

Thank you very much.

I'm not very sure whether to use the code below. Just for reference.

1. Pass one complex configurationObject instead of complex parameters.

```
class Turret {
  // constructor(texture, x, y, rotation, shieldCfg, barrelCfgList) {}
  constructor(cfg) {
    /*...*/
    this.shield = new Shield(cfg.shieldCfg.texture, cfg.shieldCfg.x, shieldCfg.y, cfg.shieldCfg.rotation)
    for(let barrelCfg of barrelCfgList){
      const barrel = new Barrel(cfg.barrelCfg.texture, cfg.barrelCfg.x, cfg.barrelCfg.y, cfg.barrelCfg.rotation)
      this.barrels.push(barrel)
    }
  }
}
```

2. Create the instances of components somewhere else, and pass these instances instead of parameters

```
class Turret {
  // constructor(texture, x, y, rotation, shieldCfg, barrelCfgList) {}
  constructor(x, y, rotation, shield, barrels) {
    /*...*/
    this.shield = shield
    this.barrels = barrels
  }
}
```

3. Factory Method Pattern ?
4. Builder Pattern ?
5. ??

   - update 1, add some instructions about background.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're going to use TypeScript. But how will you use your objects futher? Is this code will be run in browser or on server? If you're going to render UI with your code or you developing backend? If backend, how will you communicate with front end? And so on. So please describe architecture of your solution.

Comment: @Fyodor You're right. I want to use TypeScript. Thank you for your advice, and I'll fulfill the background of my question you've mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. Question became clearer. Will your game be multiplayer and will communicate with some backend?

Comment: @Fyodor Currently I didn't have such a plan ( since I might not be able to handle that). So this game will be just a single player game at the very beginning. After achieving this, I shall try to implement the features you've introduced.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is using [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system). It's the best for game development and give you a great chance to combining different parts of system in one unit/building/other game objects. You can use any way to combine it: specific classes, factory or builder.